# How to insert data in List without refreshing it

Tags: android, listactivity

I have made the following program in Android using `ListActivity`:

```
package com.infy.dataloaderdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Browser;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class DataLoaderOfDataBase extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor mCursor;
    Button mButton;
    EditText e;
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_ISBN = "isbn";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dataloaderlist);


    }


        @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();

        mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.push);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                pushDataInList();

            }

        });
    }

    public void pushDataInList(){
        String[] displayFields = new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_ISBN};

        int[] displayViews = new int[] { android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2 };

        // Cursor cur = managedQuery(android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,projection, null, null, null);
        DBAdapter dbAdapter=new DBAdapter(this);

        long l=dbAdapter.insertTitle("new");
        Log.e("l", ""+l);
        Cursor cur=null;


        //cur=dbAdapter.getTitle(2);
        cur = dbAdapter.getAllTitles();

        int i=cur.getCount();
        Log.e("c", ""+i);
        setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,cur,displayFields,displayViews));


    }

}
```

Whenever I add a data, the whole list gets refreshed. Is there any way data gets added in List without refreshing it?

Answer (score 1):

Call [setNotifyOnChange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#setNotifyOnChange%28boolean%29) with `false` to stop automatic notifications before you start adding data to the list. Once complete, call it again with `true`.

Comment: where should i use setNotifyOnChange in the code? we have to use it on some object & here we are not creating any!!!

Comment: `setNotifyOnChange` is used with `ArrayAdapter`... there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Maybe you can share the part where you add the data.